# How open file by file in a list of files?

Tags: python

How can I open every single file in a list of files, do something with the file and then go to the next file?

I have a directory with 1000 text files. I have already created a list with all the files names and now I want to open file by file. Do someone has an idea how to do that?

What I have so far:

```
from os import listdir 
from os.path import isfile, join

files_in_dir = [ f for f in listdir('nes') if isfile(join('nes',f)) ]
if f.endswith(".txt"):
   print(f)
```

Comment: `for item in files_in_dir:
    do_something(item)`

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Do you know how to open a single file, and do you know how to iterate over a list (for loop)? Both are easily searchable online, and you can combine the two quite easily. After doing some research, if you have issues, come back here with your attempt and someone will be glad to help.

Comment: Downvotes and close votes are weird. What is asked is perfectly clear! I vote up for balancing those mean votes.

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import listdir 
from os.path import isfile, join

files_in_dir = [ f for f in listdir('nes') if isfile(join('nes',f)) ]
for f in files_in_dir:
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(f, 'r') as in_file:
            for line in in_file:
                # Here you have access to lines of the opened file.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! My problem is: After my code processed the first file in the list, it stopped there instead of moving on with the second file and the third file etc. This shouldn't be the case right? Or do I have overlooked something?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one file in `files_in_dir`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a separate list to hold filenames.  Just iterate over the results of `listdir()` directly.

```
for fname in listdir('nes'):
    fname = join('nes', fname)
    if fname.endswith('.txt') and isfile(fname): 
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            # do something with open file f
```

Comment: I'd probably add a mention to the documentation :  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects